# wall climbing or indoor climbing

Tags: word-choice

I know that a climbing wall is a wall with parts to hold onto, usually inside a building, for people to practise climbing on, but is the activity that people do on a climbing wall called "wall climbing" or "indoor rock climbing"?
Which one sounds more natural?
Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: You could call it wall climbing, and the use is not fixed but, loosely, 'wall climbing' is likely to be used to contrast with, for example, 'crack climbing', 'mountaineering', etc., rather than for climbing indoors on artificial rocks.

Answer (score 2):

When I think of **wall climbing** I either think of the colloquialism meaning excessively hyperactive, or I think of some kind of Spider-Man-type guy climbing a flat surface.

**Indoor rock climbing** clearly indicates the activity you're referring to.